# Problem with Transforms in ES 8.x after upgrade from ES 7.x

Tags: elasticsearch, transform

i use Transform API for monthly aggregations of our very big daily data (2 billions per day) in ES 7.14 without any complications.

In another cluster we migrated to ES 8.x and Transform API stop working. I checked why and problem is, that transform on destination mapping create a flattened field and this kind of field dont support "empty" keys (from ES 8.x.) In my dataset i have problem with GeoIP, where on the case where i dont know GeoIP i have empty value, so this value is converted to key in destination flattened field and it is not supported now.

Is any way how to do it without change a source data ? Maybe on Transform API query i can use a script, for change GeoIP value "" to "--" or something else, but i dont know how.

Thanks, Jan

Comment: you might need to couple this with an ingest pipeline, where you do an "if null, then replace" using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-processor.html

Comment: Thanks @MarkWalkom , but if i look correctly, ingest pipeline can solve the incomming data for future indexes, but no current data in existing indexes what i need aggregate. Or i'm wrong ?

Comment: that is correct, you might be able to do something with a runtime field though